Complex Circle Spiral
Here's a complex circle spiral:

I thought this would be a well know result, but the polynomial for the complex root is unfamiliar.
All the circle centers are powers of a ~-.07+.61I root of:
$1+8 x+24 x^2+40 x^3+62 x^4+40 x^5+24 x^6+8 x^7+x^8$
The radii are the norm multiplied by a ~.765 root of
$52-104 x^2 -12 x^4 + 64 x^6 + x^8$
Is there an earlier source for this?
My solving method was inelegant, is there an easy derivation?
Okay, turns out this is one of many Doyle spirals. The polynomials don't seem to be explored. Above I give the polynomial for the 1-4 Doyle spiral.
Here's the coefficient lists for polynomials for 1-3 to 1-10:
{{1,4,10,4,1},
{1,8,24,40,62,40,24,8,1},
{1,3,10,16,47,42,78,99,64,99,78,42,47,16,10,3,1},
{1,3,16,42,102,219,356,657,918,1166,1692,1513,2054,1513,1692,1166,918,657,356,219,102,42,16,3,1},{1,4,10,26,49,80,175,272,318,488,795,862,887,1234,1527,1398,1501,1412,2050,1412,1501,1398,1527,1234,887,862,795,488,318,272,175,80,49,26,10,4,1},
{1,4,10,34,95,208,433,892,1671,2760,4701,7676,11347,15950,23650,31704,39307,51444,64364,71760,83406,97652,98586,103404,112090,103404,98586,97652,83406,71760,64364,51444,39307,31704,23650,15950,11347,7676,4701,2760,1671,892,433,208,95,34,10,4,1},
{1,5,15,35,78,152,264,424,741,1232,1839,2397,3202,4627,6568,7848,8587,9954,12914,15189,15046,14441,14655,15192,17191,12824,12026,5322,8938,8525,3943,6281,-2864,6281,3943,8525,8938,5322,12026,12824,17191,15192,14655,14441,15046,15189,12914,9954,8587,7848,6568,4627,3202,2397,1839,1232,741,424,264,152,78,35,15,5,1},
{1,5,15,35,88,222,506,1026,1962,3705,6834,11980,19722,31907,51162,79886,119482,172546,249551,355424,489996,652806,863665,1140428,1463018,1821810,2238486,2757487,3321590,3882250,4480926,5171121,5880406,6469548,7054006,7654434,8246116,8550607,8828913,9039253,9222214,9039253,8828913,8550607,8246116,7654434,7054006,6469548,5880406,5171121,4480926,3882250,3321590,2757487,2238486,1821810,1463018,1140428,863665,652806,489996,355424,249551,172546,119482,79886,51162,31907,19722,11980,6834,3705,1962,1026,506,222,88,35,15,5,1}}
I'm not sure why they are all symmetric.  Not sure why the second values are 1,4,8,3,3,4,4,5,5.  Not sure why 1-9 has a unique negative value.

Turns out it's a Doyle Spiral. The polynomials of Doyle spirals don't seem to have been explored.

You know, you could probably have gotten more interest in this if you had actually given some sort of definition for this spiral - what rules it follows - instead of just a picture and in your link some code that you apparently expect everyone to be familiar with without explanation.
